# Jasper Report Sub Table

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to generate a table in my Jasper Report in hierarchy tree stature. But I Don't get any idea how to do that. As my data is in hierarchy tree stature I can't able to populate the data in my table and also can't able to design the table in Jasper Studio.

```
@Data
public class ResponseOfReceiptDepositStatement {
    private Double depositSlipAmount;
    private String depositSlipDate;
    private String depositSlipNo;
    private Integer depositSlipId;
    List<Receipts>receiptsList;
}
```

this is my parent data class

```
@Data
public class Receipts {
    private String receiptNo;
    private String receiptDate;
    private Double receiptAmount;
    private String bankStatementDate;
    private Double bankStatementAmount;
    private Integer masterStatusCode;
}
```

this is my child data class.

I tried to generate the table as mentioned and watch several tutorial, read documentations but could not find a solution. I'm expecting to get a solution

It will be a great help if any one help me to resolve this issue. I'm a beginner in Jasper Report.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use nested Subreports to represent your tree-like table?

> Detail-Band
>
> > Detail-band  Hierarchy 1
> >
> > > Detail-band  Hierarchy 2

Create an own datasource which provides access to the hierarchy.

**Edit**
I think, you can create a subreport with static text for a header. Inside this subreport, you can add another detailband for each row in you table. If a row as subelements, you can add again a nested detail band.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpNPZ.png)

Comment: Then how can I set the static column header and pass data to sub report from my main data source?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).